# Application does not go back to app after successful authorisation through Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have integrated Google Login as well as Facebook Login in my application but when i login through Facebook it shows "You have already authorised your application". On clicking OK it does **not** go back to the application , instead it gets stuck . Why So? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> Now configure the .plist for your project:
>
> In Xcode right-click your .plist file and choose "Open As Source
>   Code". 
>   Copy & Paste the XML snippet into the body of your file
>   (...). Replace: fb{your-app-id} with your Facebook App ID
>   and the prefix fb. E.g.: fb123456. {your-app-id} with your Facebook
>   App ID. {your-app-name} with the Display Name you configured in the
>   app dashboard.

[Facebook SDK for iOS - Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started)

Just add Url URL Schemes to Info.plist [image]

if you not register URL Scheme FB app can't go to your app

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

For that in .plist file add facebook id along with "fb"prefix in URL Schemes(ex: fb1234567890) under URL types as display in screenshot.

Also add two more string "FacebookAppID"(only facebook id without any prefix ex:1234567890) and "FacebookDisplayName".

[image]